# Find out the default value for a column (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, default

I wonder if there is a way to find out the default value of some column with a simple select statement. Tried several things like:

```
SELECT * FROM all_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'tablename'
```

But I can't see the defaultvalues for the columns there. And no I do not want to use something like SQL Plus, I need a SELECT, guess there is some table providing that info?

Comment: The default value is stored in the column `DATA_DEFFAULT` of `all_tab_columns` (which **is** documented: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_2103.htm#I1020277)

Comment: Nicely answered. I'm fairly new to stackoverflow, why do add this as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: That column says <long> for all columns while in reality those columns all have a default expression like 0, 'HOST', '-', 3000, SYSDATE etc. I can see them in my PL/SQL Developer but that SELECT doesn't help me at all.

Comment: Then PL/SQL Developer cannot deal with that data type. You should find a better SQL client. I only added this as a comment because it's such an obvious answer if you bother to look at the manual. Btw: SQL*PLus *would* be able to show this.

Comment: Here is an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93fb0/1

Answer (score 14):

```
Select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_DEFAULT
from DBA_TAB_COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME';
```

Replace the Table_Name for which you want to see the default column data.

Comment: it would be better to use `like` instead of `=` as `Select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_DEFAULT from DBA_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME like '%GI_LOCATION%';` is more likely to get results.

Comment: @korefn, no, you might use LIKE if you don't know what the table name is; otherwise, `=` is appropriate.

Comment: What is DBA_TAB_COLUMNS?

Answer (score 7):

try the below query

```
Select * From USER_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME ='Table Name'
```

Answer (score 1):

Default values are in DATA_DEFAULT column from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_DEFAULT 
  FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tablename'
```

[2021-01-26] Edit:
Note that the 'tablename' parameter must match the case of real table name, as it appears on ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.  More often it will be uppercase, so may be useful use `UPPER()` function to ensure it.

```
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER('tablename')
```

Comment: When I selected from DBA_TAB_COLUMNS as suggested in another answer, I got "table or view does not exist". I guess it's either to do with my privileges or the version of Oracle. In any case, selecting from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS worked for me.

Comment: this doesn't work for me until adding Upper('tablename'). May be specific to my database table naming being all caps

Comment: @phenderbender, you are right! 'tablename' must match case with the real table name.  I've used it lowercase in my snippet to match the name used in the question.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above examples worked for me, but this one did. Key part being the 'Upper' for table_name. Perhaps specific to my team's database but if you're stuck this should work

```
SELECT a.column_name "Column",
       a.data_default "Default"
FROM   all_tab_columns a
WHERE  a.table_name = Upper('tablename')
```

Comment: Oracle converts all object names to uppercase unless they are quoted:  _create table foo_ will create table named FOO, while _create table "foo"_ will create foo